# Has there been any commentary on "Soundarya Lahari" by any scholar from Sri Shankaracharya's lineage?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, reference-request

[This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundarya_Lahari) page describes Soundarya Lahari as being authored by sage Pushpadanta and Adi Shankara. While there are many who believe this to be incorrect attribution, I am more interested to know if any scholar or acharya from the sampradaya of Sri Adi Shankara has written a proper commentary on this text. If yes, would appreciate being given the exact source material, online or offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S.S.S. Shastri and T.R.S Ayyangar have authored a commentary on the Soundarya Lahiri in English. You can download it [here](https://archive.org/download/SaundaryaLahari/SaundaryaLahariBhashyaSktEng.pdf).

Comment: @SwiftPushkar well, I didn't narrow down the scope to just pontiffs. Besides, one the authors of the book shown in the answer seems to be from an advaitin and the other a vishishtadvaitin (at least by their names). I will give this a couple more days to see if some more answers are given.

Comment: @Ambi Ok , Yes , hope that we will get some more answers after your clarification . :-)

Comment: I don't think any commentator on the Soundarya Lahiri would write from any perspective except Advaita. Because Soundarya Lahiri is purely an Advaitin work.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury I would disagree on that it is an advaitic work. It is a shakta work whose import has been extended extensively to cover for advaitic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

A total of 36 commentaries is said to have been composed on the *Saundaryalaharī*, out of which the one composed by *Lakṣmīdhara* is the most popular one. Here is a [link](https://archive.org/details/saundarya-lahari-with-9-commentaries-a-kuppuswami-1976/page/n1/mode/1up) for 9 commentaries, including the one by *Lakṣmīdhara*. Here is another [link](https://archive.org/details/SaundaryaLahariSwamiTapasyananda/mode/1up) to its exposition in English by *Svāmī Tapasyānanda* of the *Rāmakṛṣṇa Maṭha*.

Answer (score 0):

Those who say that Saundarya Lahari is an incorrect attribution to Adi Shankaracharya should study it's inner essence before commenting upon it. Saundarya Lahari is such a wonderful work comprising of extreme and complex grammatical tenets that nobody apart from the great Adi Shankaracharya could compose it. However, for the purpose of debunking some baseless accusations about it's authorship by Adi Shankaracharya, we need a corroboration.

A great Tamil Shaiva poet named 'Kaviraja Panditar (998 - 1045 CE)' has penned a commentary on each and every single verse of Saundarya Lahari way back in 11th CE itself which is available [here](http://www.tamilartsacademy.com/journals/volume19/contents.html)

Even in Prapancha Sara tantra, Padmapadacharya while commenting upon the 11th Chapter of 'Tantra vimarsha' quotes few verses of Saundarya Lahari glorifying the Supreme mother of Universe. So there's nothing erroneous in attributing Saundarya Lahari to Pushpadanta Mahagandharvaraja and Bhagavan Adi Shankara.